# shemonah esrei and moving to another location

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, shemoneh-esrei, hefsek-interruption, location

1. I heard that one can/ should, step out of שמונה עשרה if they are being disturbed and move to somewhere else. Where is the *halachic* source for this?
2. I also heard that they may move elsewhere and continue from where they left off. However, talking is not permitted. Where is the *halachic* source for this?

Comment: mishna berurah 104:2

Comment: Someone told me that I can also find this in the Shaarei Teshuvah. Do you know where it is located?

Comment: @Matt Sounds like an answer....

Answer (score 1):

The Mishna Berura ([cited by Matt](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43633/shemonah-esrei-and-moving-to-another-location#comment113311_43633)) says ([104:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.104.2)):

> **ואפילו במקום הפסד ממון אין לו להפסיק.** כתב הח"א [כלל כ"ה ס"ט] העומד
>   בתפלה ונסתפק באיזה דין איך יתפלל כגון ששכח איזה דבר בתפלה מותר לילך
>   ממקומו למקום מיוחד ולעיין שם בספר ואם מותר לשאול הדין צ"ע ונ"ל דמותר
>
> **One may not pause in the middle of davening, even in a situation of
>   monetary loss.** The Chayei Adam wrote (25:9) that someone who is
>   standing during davening, and becomes uncertain about something that
>   he is supposed to be doing; for example, he forgot to say something in
>   davening, he is allowed to walk from where he is standing to look up
>   the halacha in a *sefer*. It's unclear if he would be allowed to talk
>   to ask someone for the halacha, but it appears to me that it is
>   permissible.

(*translation mine*)

Comment: See also [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52685/changing-location-mid-way-during-shemoneh-esrei) with a different reference to MB where he says moving is allowed in case of danger but not speaking