# Changing location mid-way during Shemoneh Esrei?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, hefsek-interruption, location

In one of these hopefully rare events, I’ve found myself needing to daven Shemoneh Esrei in a hotel lobby. I tried finding a quiet place, only to realise mid-way one of the workers telling me I was not supposed to be there.

I had to move my location some distance away from my initial location, and then continue with Shemoneh Esrei. In such a situation, would my tefillah be acceptable? Or, should I have to restart from the beginning after I changed positions?

This was Maariv ... would it make any different if this was Mincha (or even Shacharit)?

Furthermore, what are the acceptable and non-acceptable reasons to permit change of location during Shemoneh Esrei?

Comment: Somewhat related answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35685

Comment: This question appears to have been answered already here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17287/what-to-do-after-interrupting-shemoneh-esreh The general rule according to the Shulchan Aruch is that you go back to a certain point and start over.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, but it seems this only discusses when people “pause” in Shemoneh Esrea - not actually walk and change location, which I feel is more of an interruption?! Or may be not? Nonetheless, is change of location qualified anywhere?

Comment: @Loewian, what is your idea in creating [tag:location]? You seem to be applying it to questions about locating objects in local space as well as questions about locations on the globe, which seem to be two different topics. The latter may be pretty much the same thing as [tag:geography].

Comment: @IsaacMoses I put an explanation to distinguish it from geography in its description.

Comment: @IsaacMoses (Which isn't to say that some questions might not merit both tags.)

Comment: @IsaacMoses There are tag*s* for time; only stands to reason there should be one for space (beyond just geography, which is much more limited conceptually).

Comment: @Loewian (Link to your suggested edit in case it's not live yet: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/21698), I'd recommend just using it for locating objects in local space, and leaving the global kind to [tag:geography].

Comment: @IsaacMoses I thought that's what I indicated. Please feel free to edit if you think that's not clear. (Though I could still conceive of questions that straddle the line or merit both tags...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Mishna Brura 104:10](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.104.10?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) rules that a "hefsek tfila" (a pause in prayer) is only speaking and not walking. So in case of need (he speaks of danger), it is permitted to move and pick up prayer from the new location, but one should not speak. If there is no need, then one should not change his place.

The poskim in Israel say clearly that in case of danger (e.g., animals, rockets), one has to change his place (e.g., to go to a shelter). See for instance [R Shlomo Aviner here](http://www.ravaviner.com/2014/07/shut-mivtza-tzuk-eitan-q-on-operation.html).

See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22279/rockets-from-gaza-while-praying) for a related MY question with sources on the need to restart or not from the start depending how long the interruption is.

I would assume (but don't have a source) that it is better to change places at the end of a brakha if one doesn't endanger his life by doing so.

PS. There is a logic to this as well. During shmone esre we are speaking to the King of the World. Interrupting this discussion by speaking with someone else is problematic. Changing place and continuing the discussion - much less so.